# What's the hidden services threat model after a key compromise?

Tags: onion-services, threat-models

When a hidden service private key got compromised and an adversary uses our hidden service to serve its own TCP stream can we detect it or can he do that silently or sniff on our hidden service's traffic?

What can an adversary do when he/she owns our private key?

Answer (score 4):

The stolen key can be used to spoof your host. Traffic directed to the .onion will randomly go to your server or the person who stole it, even in the middle of a session. Once your key has be compromised you should replace it ASAP. I do not believe that it would allow the person with the key to read the traffic any easier. The best way to tell if some one else is listing for your .onion site is to take your server's Tor connection off line and try to load the .onion site.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the adversary can also MITM any connections to the original owner of hidden service, if they play things just right.